# Value of Type 'uiStackView' Has No Member 'image'

Tags: swift

import UIKit
// MARK: Properties
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
{

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField:UITextField!;
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIStackView!


@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton)
    {

        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"

    }


override func viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //self = viewController
        nameTextField.delegate = self

    }
        //UItextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        //keyboard goes when done

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }

func imagePickController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage


    self.photoImageView.image = selectedImage


    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am working on the tutorial for Xcode and am running into the issue I listed above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't photoImageView be a UIImageView then?

```
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your response!